# CSMA/CA manupilation

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

Is there a way to manupilate CSMA/CA code in linux or to make an Android application that uses a modified version of CSMA/CA. I would like to change the backoff time and make some analysis. Any suggestions would be helpful on where to get the source code in linux. or for an Android application is there a way to access the CSMA/CA settings or code?

Answer (score 1):

I not familiar with Android, but I do have some knowledge about linux Kernel. CSMA/CA mechanism is a part of the MAC layer of ieee 802.11 protocol. The implementation of ieee80211 in linux kernel is divided into twe sub-layers: the general layer named mac80211, and the device specified layer like ath9k or broadcom. The source code of mac80211 is located in /net/mac80211 directory, while the source code of device specified driver is located in /drivers/net/wireless.

The backoff time is controlled by the device specified driver. For example. for ath9k, you should pay attention to the variables/macros `CW_MIN`, `CW_MAX`, and `IFS`, and function `ath9k_hw_resettxqueue` in /ath/ath9k/mac.c.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Can I edit the device specified driver source code and would it impact all the applications running or can I specify it differently for different apps? Also, if you know any links or articles I can read or follow that would be great. Thanks again

Comment: Fatal error in kernel space may cause the whole system to break. So I have to say that editing the driver source code may have unexpected side effects. If you are new to linux device driver, you need to read Linux Device Driver 3rd Edition.